# Why Kruti dev font is smaller then other fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-family, hindi

I added **kruti dev** font in my project with other fonts like latto. in one line when we use both font, kruti is smaller then other. Below is the image,
[image]

I don't have any element selector for **kruti**, is there any way, so we can fix this.

Comment: Please post your questions along with the relevant code.

Comment: @AllanJebaraj all its not a issue of code, its a issue of font.

Comment: then use another font.

Comment: need matra's in project and kruti only support matra in hindi